# How can I get the JTextArea to appear above the JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

When I add both of them to `SOUTH` using `BorderLayout`, only the `JTextArea` appears. I'm using the text field as an input which is then displayed in the text area as an output above it with some other text.

It works if I set the text area to `NORTH` but it doesn't look great.

```java
JPanel cmdPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

field = new JTextField(20);
cmdPanel.add(field, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

JTextArea output=new JTextArea();
output.setEditable(false);
output.setLineWrap(true);
cmdPanel.add(output, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

This image shows how it looks now with the TextArea set to NORTH.
I'm just trying to have it appear over the TextField and move up
the screen as outputs are added.

[image]

Comment: You should read the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) section of the Oracle Swing tutorial. Or more specifically [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but from the screen capture of your running app, it looks like you are explicitly setting the size of the `JFrame`. Rather than doing that, you should call method [pack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--). Note that you should call that method **after** you have added both your `JTextField` and `JTextArea` to the `cmdPanel` and also after you have added `cmdPanel` to the `JFrame`. Also you should call method `setVisible` on the `JFrame` after calling method `pack()`.

You should also make sure that the `JTextArea` has a preferred size before adding it to `cmdPanel`. One way to do this is by calling the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea-int-int-) that takes the number of rows and columns parameters.

Maybe also wrap the `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane` and make that the "center" component of `cmdPanel`?

```java
JPanel cmdPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

field = new JTextField(20);
cmdPanel.add(field, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

JTextArea output=new JTextArea(10, 20);
output.setEditable(false);
output.setLineWrap(true);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(output);
cmdPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add two components in the same position (i.e BorderLayout.PAGE_END). To add more components in the same position, you should create a JPanel, add the components on it and then add the JPanel to the desirable position (i.e BorderLayout.PAGE_END).